# Infinitesimal generator and transition semigroup

Tags: probability, probability-theory, markov-process

Let $\mathcal L$ be the infinitesimal Generator of a Markov Prozess.
Assume we know, that applied to some suitable, given function $f$ we know that we get the function $a(x)$ i.e
$$\mathcal L f(x)=a(x)$$ 
Is it possible to directly conclude $e^{t \mathcal L} f(x)=?$

I know, that $e^{t \mathcal L}$ could be replaced by the transition semigroup and we could compute that, but is there a way to use our previous knowledge of $a(x)$ to arrive there aswell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Example:** The Markov process is standard $1$-dimensional Brownian motion. Consider $f_0(x):=1$ and $f_1(x)=x$. Then $\mathcal L f_0(x) =\mathcal L f_1(x) =0$ for all $x$, but $e^{t\mathcal L}f_0(x)=f_0(x)$ while $e^{t\mathcal L}f_1(x)=f_1(x)$ fo all $x$.

Comment: Thanks! Just a quick question: do we have monotonicity when changing from $\mathcal L$ to $e^{t\mathcal L}$? It seems reasonable although I can't see a rigorous proof for it

Comment: Here is one sort of monotonicity that's present: If $\mathcal L f\ge 0$ (pointwise) then $t\mapsto e^{t\mathcal L}f(x)$ is non-decreasing for each $x$. Such a function $f$ is *subharmonic*.

Comment: Thanks @JohnDawkins
I appreciate that you even answer my comments. Just one last question concerning this topic that I stumbled upon.
Assume we have $-a f(x) \le \mathcal L f(x)$ for a given positive, bounded function $f$ and $a>0$. Is it true, that $e^{-ta} f(x) \le e^{t \mathcal L}f(x)$  ??

Comment: Yes.  And he condition $a>0$ is unnecessary.

Comment: Thank you @JohnDawkins , is there an easy way to see/derive/proof it?